# How to bill variable amounts (per-seat model), month to month

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to bill my customers in a per-seat model. Future payments looks great, but as I see are not available for the REST API (web app), at least not in my country (Uruguay). Am I right?

Alternatives? Reference transactions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, future payments are only available when you are developing the mobile application. For the web app version, you can consider to use the Reference Transaction where at first you set an agreement with a customer and then you can use the [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) API to billed your customer in future.Wanted to know more? Click [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/) for the API related info.